# jquery img width with only height set

Tags: jquery, width

i have a set of images (a gallery) with only the Height set `img: height:200px;` so all images have the same height but different width and i need to get the width of all images.

is that possible?

currently i am using:

```
var accum_width = 0;
$('.scroll-content-item img').each(function() {
accum_width += $(this).width() + 20;
});
alert(accum_width);

$( ".scroll-content" ).css('width', accum_width);
```

but i am getting 100 (margins). any ideas?

thank you

Comment: Yes, wait until they are loaded, loop through them, and sum their width.

Comment: Jonas asks: `To clarify, you want all the widths combined? Or as a list of numbers?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the clarifications

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var widthSum = 0;
    $('img').each(function(){
       widthSum += this.width;
    });
    // do something with the widthSum here..
});
```

i use the `$(window).load` to make sure that the images have loaded.

Comment: awswm! thanks a lot @GabyakaG.Petrioli! works like a charm, i think my problem was the .load to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Use each to iterate through img tags

```
$('img').each(function(){
   alert(this.width);  
})
```

If your images have some common class then use class selector.

```
$('img.classname').each(function(
   alert(this.width);  //with javascript
   alert($(this).width());  //with jQuery
})
```

Comment: width/height are direct properties of images.. `this.height` will do

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the width function: http://api.jquery.com/width/

```
$('img').width();
```

Comment: He's already using the jQuery Width(). The OP whats to sum of all widths.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
var widthcoll = $.each(imagecollection,function(){
return $(this).width();
});
```

Thanks